# Ionic 4 & Firebase integration

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, ionic4

So, I'm quite a noob when it comes to ionic 4 firebase integration. Basically I've managed to get the firebase authentication to work, but the problem is I can't seem to save the user's input in the sign up page to firebase database. I need it to work as I would like to link the user to his/her checklist.

This is my sign-up page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Platform, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { LoadingController, ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';


//disable side menu
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.page.scss'],
})
export class SignupPage implements OnInit {

  email: string = '';
  password: string = '';
  error: string = '';
  username: string = '';

  constructor(
    private fireauth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router,
    public menuCtrl: MenuController,
    private toastController: ToastController, 
    private platform: Platform, 
    public loadingController: LoadingController,
    public alertController: AlertController
  ) { }

  async openLoader() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please Wait ...',
      duration: 2000
    });
    await loading.present();
  }
  async closeLoading() {
    return await this.loadingController.dismiss();
  }

  signup() {
    this.fireauth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.user) {
          console.log(res.user);
          this.updateProfile();
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(`login failed ${err}`);
        this.error = err.message;
      });
  }

  updateProfile() {
    this.fireauth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        user.updateProfile({
          displayName: this.username
        })
          .then(() => {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          })
      }
    })
  }

  async presentToast(message, show_button, position, duration) {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: message,
      showCloseButton: show_button,
      position: position,
      duration: duration
    });
    toast.present();
  }


  ionViewWillEnter (){
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
  }

  ngOnInit(){}

}
```

Comment: Hi, @Oddie123, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide the code you're currently using to save the user's input to the Firebase database? That would help us evaluate what might be an issue with your current code, and provide more focused guidance.

Comment: Hi @JeremyCaney, I've updated my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you aren't using the firebase database. The `user.updateProfile` method stores the displayName property in the Firebase Auth system. That information is saved in the Firebase Auth system.

Comment: oh i see, is there a way i can store them into firebase database instead because most of the tutorials I saw uses firebase auth for sign-up and login page :/

Comment: Firebase Auth works only to handle the authentication for you, another service that Firebase provides is Database, so if you need to store the information you can also work with Firebase Database use both services.

Comment: Can you like guide me through this? So do i just change the fireauth in " this.fireauth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user)" to firestore instead?

Comment: hey, I've found this blog post (https://www.positronx.io/ionic-firebase-authentication-tutorial-with-examples/) i've tried it but i still don't see the user's input in my firebase console.

Comment: What do you mean with still don't see the user's input in your firebase console? Auth Console? Or into Database Console?